# Filter Lines to write

Tags: c#, file-io, datagridview, streamwriter

I have the following code which takes data from a `DataGridView` and writes it to a csv file . The csv file has 5 columns . However I only want the data for selected clients to be written to the file , the client name is selected from a comboBox . The below code writes all the datagrid values to the file however I want to only write the rows where the ClientName is Equal to the combobox value however I am unable to get this working

```
  // inventory export 
        private void btnExportShareClass_Click( object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //SET GRID
            DataGridView gridIn ;
            string outputFile = Inv_Export_savePath.Text;

        gridIn = Inv_DataGrid;
        //VAR holding client combobox
        string Selected_Combo = Inv_ClientList_Export_Combobox.Text ;


        //test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
        if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
        {
           string value = "";
           DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
           StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

           //write header rows to csv
           for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
           {
              if (i > 0)
              {
                 swOut.Write(",");
              }
              swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);
           }

           swOut.WriteLine();

           //write DataGridView rows to csv
           for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
           {
              if (j > 0)
              {

                        swOut.WriteLine();

              }

              dr = gridIn.Rows[j];

              for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
              {
                 if (i > 0)
                 {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                 }

                 value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                 //replace comma's with spaces
                 value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                 //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                 value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "); 

                 swOut.Write(value);
              }
           }
           swOut.Close();
        }

    }


         for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
              {
                 if (i > 0)
                 {
                      gridIn.Rows[i].ToString().Contains(Inv_ClientList_Export_Combobox.Text );
                    swOut.Write(",");
                 }

                 value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                 //replace comma's with spaces
                 value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                 //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                 value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " "); 

                 swOut.Write(value);
              }
```

Comment: You shouldn't find any problem to perform this filtering with a simple condition telling whether the given cell should be written or not. If you want further help, you would have to provide more information regarding how the name of the clients are related with the DataGrid cells.

Comment: I would suggest bind your datagrid to collectionviewsource and have it filtered on change of combobox's selection changed. Then your viewmodel will always know the filtered items so you just serialize that to file and no need to sorting yourself

Comment: I've tried using an IF GRIDIN.Contains SELECTED_COMBO (this contains the value of the combobox) but it doesnt work  , Could anyone provide a code example of how to filter ?

Comment: @VaroCarbas , I've tried using an if statement which converts the rows to strings and writes the row if it contains the value selected in combobox but it just writes the entire datagrid for some reason

Comment: If you want to make sure that value (value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString()) does not contain SELECTED_COMBO, you can use if(!value.Contains(SELECTED_COMBO)) without any problem. If you want to check a different cell, just make sure that the index/value is right (e.g., you can generate a string variable like "value" without any problem) and it would also work without any problem. Could you please include the code you tried?

Comment: @varocarbas I want to only include the client selected in the combobox , I've edited th question above to show my code I've tried

Comment: Also bear in mind that "GridView" can be understood as a general reference to certain type of controls, but better being clear about the exact type. One thing is DataGridView and another thing is GridView; even it gets messier by bearing in mind that you are not saying the exact platform: "GridView" in ASP/WPF/Winforms refer to different things. I have corrected your question accordingly.

Comment: Firstly, gridIn.Rows[i].ToString().Contains(Inv_ClientList_Export_Combobox.Text ); as you wrote it does not make anything, you have to include it in a condition/assign to boolean variable. Secondly, if what you want is looking for the given string through the whole row (all the cells in the row) you cannot do it in this way: you have to go cell by cell either via loop or LINQ. Please explain the exact condition you want to meet; example: "if I am analysing the cell 1,1, I want to check if the client name is contained in any cell of row 1, in cell 1,1?" Please, be more clear.

Comment: Sorry about that , The slected combo box lets you select the client name , the client name is the 3rd column , I want to search through the datagrid and if the 3rd column value is equal to that of the combox box i want to write that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems like you should rely on a simple condition to perform the filtering you want. Here you have a corrected version of your code:

```
//test to see if the DataGridView has any rows
if (gridIn.RowCount > 0)
{
    string value = "";
    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
    StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter(outputFile);

    //write header rows to csv
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            swOut.Write(",");
        }
        swOut.Write(gridIn.Columns[i].HeaderText);
    }

    swOut.WriteLine();

    //write DataGridView rows to csv
    bool previousSkipped = false;
    for (int j = 0; j <= gridIn.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if (j > 0 && !previousSkipped)
        {
            swOut.WriteLine();
        }

        dr = gridIn.Rows[j];

        for (int i = 0; i <= gridIn.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString().ToLower().Contains(Selected_Combo.ToLower()))
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                }

                value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                //replace comma's with spaces
                value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                swOut.Write(value);
                previousSkipped = false;
            }
            else
            {
                previousSkipped = true; //To avoid using swOut.WriteLine(); more than required
            }
        }
    }
    swOut.Close();
}
```

This code checks whether the value of the third column (index 2) in the given row equals the content of the variable `Selected_Combo`, by ignoring caps (comparison of both strings `ToLower()`); and only in case of meeting this condition writes the given cell to the file.